# Marginal characteristic function from a multivariate charateristic function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, probability, correlation-functions, statistics

[I am posting this question here and not in Mathematics Stack Exchange because I will be using conventions as they are usually used in statistical physics (especially the notation is more involved in pure statistics).]

**Given a multivariable characteristic function $G(k_1,k_2)$, what is the marginal characteristic function $G(k_1)$?**

*First some definitions*. For continuous stochastic variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, the characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the probability distribution (I drop any pre-factors for simplicity).

$G(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\ e^{ikx}\ p(x)$

$G(k_1,k_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ e^{ik_1x_1}\  e^{ik_2x_2}\ p(x_1,x_2)$

The marginal probability for the variable $x_1$ is then
$p(x_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ p(x_1,x_2)$

Using the above three definitions, I want to show that (if true)
$$G(k_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk_2\ G(k_1,k_2)$$

---

**My attempt at a proof**:

I start by writing $G(k_1)$ as the inverse Fourier transform:
$$
G(k_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ e^{ik_1x_1}\ p(x_1)
$$
Now I write $p(x_1)$ as the marginal probability of the multivariate probability distribuion $p(x_1,x_2)$:
$$
G(k_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ e^{ik_1x_1}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ p(x_1,x_2)
$$
Now I need to get a $G(k_1,k_2)$ in there somehow, so I multiply by $1=e^{-ik_2x_2}e^{ik_2x_2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
G(k_1) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ e^{ik_1x_1}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ e^{-ik_2x_2}e^{ik_2x_2}\ p(x_1,x_2)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ e^{-ik_2x_2}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ e^{ik_1x_1}\ e^{ik_2x_2}\ p(x_1,x_2)
\end{align}
$$
which looks *almost* like what I need, except for the extra integrand $e^{-ik_2x_2}$, which makes it impossible to transform the integral into anything I know. Similar approaches (in which I substitute my known definitions largely end up with the same problem). How can I proceed? Which other approach can I use to show what I need?

Comment: The conjecture is wrong. Integrating over $k_2$ gives a Dirac delta..

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, although I am not 100% on the validity of the last step:

---

Begin with the definition of the marginal probability:
$$
p(x_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ p(x_1,x_2)
$$
which I now multiply by $e^{ik_1x_1}$ and integrate over $x_1$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ p(x_1)\ e^{ik_1x_1} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ p(x_1,x_2)\ e^{ik_1x_1}
$$
The LHS is now the defintion of the characteristic function of $p(x_1)$, $G(k_1)$. The RHS is *almost* the definition of the characteristic function of $p(x_1,x_2)$, but it's missing a factor of $e^{ik_2x_2}$. This factor is identically $1$ if $k_2=0$. So I insert it under the condition that $k_2=0$ (**Is this a valid step?**):
$$
G(k_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_2\ p(x_1,x_2)\ e^{ik_1x_1}\ e^{ik_2x_2}
$$
Now the RHS is the definition of the characteristic function of $p(x_1,x_2)$ evaluated at $k_2=0$, $\left.G(k_1,k_2)\right|_{k_2=0}$. So finally:
$$
G(k_1) = \left.G(k_1,k_2)\right|_{k_2=0}
$$